# Storyboard too LONG.. How do I design for standard size?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I've just started developing.
I downloaded 4.5.2 and registered etc.
I have it all working on my 3GS but its squashed..
Obviously its the new iPhone5 size..
How can I get it to the normal size?
What should I consider to deal with this?
Thanks in advance
Mat

Comment: If you want to subscribe your app to the store it HAVE to build for Iphone 5 too. So actually there's no way to hide from this I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to design for the smaller screen, then in IB you can change the size of your controllers from "Inferred", which is the default, to "Retina 3.5 Full Screen". It's the topmost pull down menu under Simulated Metrics. As Noah said though, you do need to make sure it works on the larger screen as well.

Comment: @MHG, as a new SO user, you should know that when someone answers your question, you should accept their answer.